# Как в RecyclerView вывести текст о том, что он пуст?

Tags: android, recyclerview

RecyclerView заполняется списком через LinearLayoutManager, вопрос в том, что когда список пуст, как в RecyclerView вывести текст о том, что он пуст?

Comment: Добавить в него один айтем, отличный от других, и вставить туда TextView c надписью "Список пуст"

Comment: Используйте метод 'setEmptyView'. Вот тут пример: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217436/how-to-show-an-empty-view-with-a-recyclerview

Comment: Если кастомный адаптер то как по мне лучше всего создать отдельный вид, и его вытягивать. или же сделать дополнительный спрятаный блок, и его показывать.

Comment: @AndreyEKB пример действительно рабочий, но где вы там видели метод 'setEmptyView'? Метод setEmptyView не работает с RecyclerView.

Comment: @ZigZag я так понял это кастомный метод

Comment: В своем приложении я использовал второй ответ с кастомным методом

Comment: @SharOFF там  несколько ответов, но все реализованы не на использование самого setEmptyView в RecyclerView, а на получение того же результата, что дает использование  setEmptyView, что в принципе и работает. Сам же метод андроида setEmptyView не работает с RecyclerView, отчего и возникли эти варианты решения проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем вот, что я изобрел - создал кастомный адаптер:

```
private class EmptyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_empty_my, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {};
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Мой лайоут:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_my_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/empty_list"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

И в коде вставил

```
List<MyModel> models = MyModelLab.get().getList();
if(models.size() == 0){
    mMyRecyclerView.setAdapter(new EmptyAdapter());
    return;
}
```

Решение было создано до этой темы, просто не работало, как оказалось вся проблема была в том, что в методе getItemCount() возвращал 0, из-за этого на экране ничего не возвращалось, заменил на 1 и блок вывелся на экран