# Скрыть View, если RecyclerView пуст

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, view

Есть Activity, в макете которой, для отображения списка, размещен RecyclerView. В этой же разметке, поверх RecyclerView, находится TextView. Это надпись "Добавить запись" на представленных скриншотах.
В RecyclerView новую запись можно добавить, нажав по значку "+" в правом верхнем углу скриншота. Появится диалоговое окно (DialogFragment) с формой создания новой записи.
Удаление записи происходит свайпом.
Хочу сделать так, что бы при при пустом RecyclerView надпись "Добавить запись" отображалась. Но при появлении в списке RecyclerView хотя бы одной записи, надпись исчезала. Соответственно, при удалении последней записи в списке, нужно что бы надпись снова появлялась. И да, все это динамически: добавил запись в список - надпись исчезла, удалил последнюю - появилась.

Погуглил, поискал решение здесь. Нашел пару вопросов: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553956/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-recyclerview-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82) и на en-SO [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217436/how-to-show-an-empty-view-with-a-recyclerview), но в решении моего вопроса это не помогло.

Попробовал сделать скрытие TextView при появлении записи в RecyclerView так:
в активити в методе onCreate добавил условие

```
TextView noticeAdd = findViewById(R.id.noticeAdd);
    if (linearLayoutManager.getItemCount() == 0) {
        noticeAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else noticeAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

В результате это работает только если обновить активити. Нужно же, что бы сразу надпись исчезала и появлялась при добавлении/удалении записи в RecyclerView. Поясню в скриншотах.
[image: поведение приложения]
**Screenshot 1**: В списке RecyclerView не добавлено ни одной записи, соответственно TextView  отображается.
**Screenshot 2**: Ожидаемый результат. Добавил запись в RecyclerView, надпись исчезла. Так должно быть.
**Screenshot 3**: Как сейчас есть на самом деле. При добавлении записи, надпись "Добавить запись" все равно остается, хотя должна исчезнуть. Исчезает только при обновлении (пересоздании) активити.
И да, вариант с onResume не подходит, удаление, напомню, происходит свайпом.
Как скрыть/показать View (надпись "Добавить запись"), при добавлении/удалении записи в RecyclerView не обновляя активити?

Comment: Код скрытия Textview нужно ставить не в функции создания View, а в части обновления адаптера RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге, я сделал это с помощью наблюдателя адаптера RecyclerView.
В активити, содержащем RecyclerView, в **onCreate**:

```
TextView noticeAddEx = findViewById(R.id.noticeAddEx);  //Надпись, которую нужно скрыть
    Check check = new Check();
    check.showHide_View(arrayList, noticeAddEx);//При создании активити, если RV пуст, то показать надпись. Иначе скрыть.
    createPlanAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override   //Скрыть/показать View при добавлении в список RV
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            check.showHide_View(arrayList, noticeAddEx);
        }

        @Override   //Скрыть/показать View при удалении из списка RV
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            check.showHide_View(arrayList, noticeAddEx);
        }
    });
```

*arrayList* - модель данных из БД для отображения в RecyclerView
В отдельном классе **Check**, создал метод:

```
public void showHide_View(ArrayList<?> arrayList, View viewHideShow) {  
        if(arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            viewHideShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else viewHideShow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

**AdapterDataObserver** просто следит за добавлением и удалением записей в RecyclerView и проверяет условие на пустой arrayList.
Позже появилась необходимость сделать удаление записи в RecyclerView еще и из диалога, по нажатию кнопки. Мне бы пришлось вставлять условия проверки в разные места: при добавлении, при удалении свайпом, при удалении через диалог. А так просто адаптер следит за двумя операциями - добавления и удаления записи в RV, ему не важно с помощью чего это реализовано.
С помощью этого же метода **showHide_View** добавил скрытие/отображение надписи у других RecyclerView в приложении, т.к. параметры метода позволяют передавать ArrayList с разными типами данных. Да и скрывать/отбражать не только TextView, но вообще любой view.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый раз когда обновляте лист вы должны проверить лист на isEmpty(). Если лист пустой тогда надо показывать textView иначе скрыть.

```
 public void setDataToAdapter(List<Note> notes) {
        if (notes.isEmpty()) {
            // show textView
        } else {
            // hide textView
        }
        adapter.setNotes(notes);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

и при свайпе

```
public void onSwipe(int position) {
        notes.remove(position);
        if (notes.isEmpty()) {
            // show textView
        } else {
            // hide textView
        }
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я это делаю примерно так:

лейаут:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        style="@style/RecyclerViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/recordRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/emptyText"
        android:textSize="@dimen/increased_text_size"
        android:text="Press (+) button to add record"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_narrow_margin"/>
```

Далее при раскрутке `RecyclerView` в `onCreateView()` пишем примерно такой код:

```
int itemCount = adapter.getItemCount();
if(itemCount > 0)
   binding.emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
   binding.emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

`binding` - это [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) лейаута, `adapter` - соответственно адаптер списка.